# Errors with gspread with Python

Tags: python, gspread

I'm trying to use gspread API with ticketmaster API

This's the code for the json file should **I refer to json Credentials file of Google APIs as I did or the file of the json data itself?**

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from pprint import pprint

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("ticketmaster-350616-ae26457d3166.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)   

sheet = client.open("tutorial").sheet1  # Open the spreadhseet
data = sheet.get_all_records()  # Get a list of all records
```

This's the json file that contains the data that I mean
e.g.

```
  {  "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "speeqedy-octane-317516",
      "private_key_id": "yyyyyyyyy",
      "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\xxxxxxxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "client_email": "cybor@speedy-octane-313216.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "client_id": "102481923285078876543",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/cybor%40speedy-octane-317516.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
```

These are the Errors I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 128, in open
    properties = finditem(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\gspread\utils.py", line 88, in finditem
    return next(item for item in seq if func(item))
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\xampp\htdocs\Ticket\ticketmaster.py", line 29, in <module>
    sheet = client.open("tutorial").sheet1  # Open the spreadhseet
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 138, in open
    raise SpreadsheetNotFound
gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound
```

Comment: In case this is an actual `private_key`  that can be used for some kind of authentication to some kind of service, you should revoke access with that key ASAP. (Someone tried to edit it away, but that won't help much, it'll still be visible in the edit history.)

Comment: True I forgot the edit history. And yes this key can give someone's access to any google API. and any resources shared with this email address `cybor@speedy-octane-313216.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. so yes please revoke/delete it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is when you try to open the spreadsheet here: `sheet = client.open("tutorial").sheet1`.

As the error message says:

```
...
    raise SpreadsheetNotFound
gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound
```

Gspread cannot find this spreadsheet.

As mentioned in the documentation [in open method documentation](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.3.2/api.html#gspread.Client.open) and in the [authentication documentation](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.3.2/oauth2.html#for-bots-using-service-account) ( bullet point 6, just below the service account file where it says "very important"):

- you must share your spreadsheet with this email (the email from the service account)
- if the spreadsheet does not exists it will raise the `SpreadshertNotFound` exception